# Interpolate only one value of a TimeSerie using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.core.series.TimeSeries` named `ts` like this:

```
timestamp
2013-08-11 14:23:50        0.3219
2013-08-11 14:23:49        0.3222
2013-08-11 14:19:14        0.3305
2013-08-11 00:47:15        0.3400
2013-08-11 00:47:15.001    0.3310
2013-08-11 00:47:15.002    0.3310
2013-08-10 22:38:15.003    0.3400
2013-08-10 22:38:14        0.3403
2013-08-10 22:38:13        0.3410
```

Index of this TimeSerie are irregularly spaced.

I would like to have value of `ts` for a given datetime such as `2013-08-11 14:20:00`

I just need to interpolate **ONE** value, not the whole TimeSerie

I just want to interpolate data using a linear function between the previous index (`2013-08-11 14:23:49`) and the next index (`2013-08-11 14:19:14`)

Comment: So, to make things a little bit more clearer, for every two events that didn't happened in the same minute, you want an interpolation that will bi placed on the round minute after the first event happened?

Comment: Sorry, assume that index doesn't have duplicate values (2013-08-11 00:47:15:000, 2013-08-11 00:47:15:001, 2013-08-11 00:47:15:002, 2013-08-11 00:47:15:003)

Comment: Even then you have multiple values inside one minute: 22:38 has 3 values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a subset of the Series including only the entry above and below your target. Then use `interpolate`.

```
def interpolate(ts, target):
    ts1 = ts.sort_index()
    b = (ts1.index > target).argmax() # index of first entry after target
    s = ts1.iloc[b-1:b+1]
    # Insert empty value at target time.
    s = s.reindex(pd.to_datetime(list(s.index.values) + [pd.to_datetime(target)]))
    return s.interpolate('time').loc[target]
```

Example:

```
interpolate(ts, '2013-08-11 14:20:00')
2013-08-11 14:20:00    0.329112
```

Answer (score 8):

Thank-you Dan Allan.  I'm afraid I don't have the reputation to comment but Dan Allan's interpolate function raises an exception if asked to interpolate a time already defined in the ts index.  E.g.

```
s = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-26 00:00:00')
e = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-26 00:10:00')
ts=pd.Series([0,8000],index=[s,e])
interpolate(ts,pd.to_datetime('2015-08-26 00:00:00'))
```

My minor modification of the above is:

```
def interpolate(ts, target):
    if target in ts.index:
        return ts[target]
    ts1 = ts.sort_index()
    b = (ts1.index > target).argmax() # index of first entry after target
    s = ts1.iloc[b-1:b+1]
    # Insert empty value at target time.
    s = s.reindex(pd.to_datetime(list(s.index.values) + [pd.to_datetime(target)]))
    return s.interpolate(method='time').loc[target]
```